# R: How to get the index of the closest smaller element given a constrained value

Tags: r

I have a list in R

```
b <-c(230, 275,234,400)
```

And I want to get the index of the element having value less than 280. As a result  want to get index of 275 only.

What is the proposed solution? Maybe using `match()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
match(max(b[b<280]), b)
#[1] 2
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!